# Which forces act on a ball in the air (including air friction) including their equation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, projectile, simulations, drag

I am trying to write a ballistic throw simulation with the forces which act on the ball I take into consideration being the gravitational force, and drag. I know that the Magnus effect and another force are acting from the sidespin, but I couldn't find the equation for both of them. If you can please link/write an explanation for both of them with their equation I would appreciate it.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/489777/what-is-the-magnus-coefficient-for-a-golf-ball

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general equation of motion for a rotating ball in the Earth's gravitational field with no wind at all is:
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\vec v=-\underbrace{k\,v\,\vec v}_{\mathrm{wind\, force}}+\underbrace{\epsilon\,\left(\vec \omega \times\vec v\right)}_{\mathrm{Magnus\, force}}+\vec g.$$

- $~k$ ballistic coefficient
- $~\epsilon=\frac{\rho_{wind}}{\rho_{ball}}$
- $~\vec \omega=$ the ball's angular velocity vector, parallel to the axis of rotation
- $\vec v=\begin{bmatrix}
    v_x \\
    v_y \\
    v_z \\
  \end{bmatrix}= $ the ball's velocity components
- $\vec g=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    -g \\
  \end{bmatrix}$