Magnus Force of a Spinning Baseball
I'm a total physics novice, and I recently picked up Adair's The Physics of Baseball. In describing Magnus effect (page 12-13 of the book), he describes a situation in which one side of the baseball is traveling farther than the other as it moves to the plate (see attached). If you are taking two opposite points on a ball and measuring the amount of travel via rotation, wouldn't the distance traveled for these points always be the same? The book is aimed a lay audience, so it is deliberately non-technical. If anyone has any good references for understanding the details here, they would be much appreciated.


You can always check this out: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/834327/142234

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/489777/

The author is not talking about a particular dot on the baseball surface.
No part of the surface remains on either side, they rotate around.
Think about a rolling wheel. The part of the wheel
which touches the ground is not moving forward. The uppermost part of the wheel is
moving forward twice as fast as the center.
If we draw dots on the edge of the wheel, and keep track of their forward progress,
we find they do most of their forward progress when they are on the upper half of the wheel.
At every instant, the upper half of the wheel is traveling faster and farther than the lower half.
On the baseball, the air feels the ball surface pressing against it.
On one side, the spin of the ball adds to the surface speed, on the other side, the spin subtracts from it.
On one side, more total surface travels past the air, interacting with it.

Thanks. I understand the rotation component, but it's not clear to me how you are supposed to measure either distance or velocity in this context. If we start with a fixed point on the ball, is the distance the author is referring to the path traveled by that point around the ball? Or is this a reference to the distance traveled between release and arrival at the target? Do you know of any references that just lay out the math for such applications like this?

The book apparently uses the linear length of the "rub", the relative distance between the "still" air on each side of the baseball, and the linear equator of the ball passing by the air. The 60 feet traveled by the ball rubs 60 feet of air across both sides of the baseball. The spinning rubs an additional 11 feet (15 circumferences) of surface on one side of the baseball, and prevents 11 feet of rub on the other side.

The displacement vectors for the points on opposite sides of the (spinning) ball will be nearly equal (and have nearly equal length, modulo the diameter of the ball.)  Very heuristically (and only heuristically), it might help if you imagine two microscopic helicopters hovering just above the surface of the baseball, trying to follow the ball on opposite sides: both helicopters will need to overcome air that is dragged along the surface of the ball, but one helicopter (the one on the first-base side) will need to move at a much faster air-speed than the other, and so (from its perspective) it had to travel a longer "air-distance" than the other.
